# Why is this html/css/jquery Carousel slideshow not working?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have tried to do a search, but could not figure it out.

It seems something is wrong with the Jquery code, i get stuck at the first picture and the slider is not moving anywhere.

Here is the full code, there are no external files, it is all on one html.index page.

This does not run on Chrome, Firefox nor IE.

It is supposed to be a 5 pictures Carousel slideshow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>carousselo</title>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascrpt">

$(document).ready(function() {
                  setInterval(function() {
                  $('#caroussel  ul').animate({marginLeft:'-800px'},2000,function(){

  $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
  $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
});

},4000);                 

 });
```

Comment: Add working code snippet please.

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $ul = $('#caroussel  ul');
    setInterval(function() {
      $ul.animate({marginLeft:'-800px'},2000,function(){
        $ul.find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        $ul.css({marginLeft:0});
      });
    },4000);                 

 });
```

EDIT: here is the complete working script

carousselo

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        *{ margin: 0; padding: ; } 
        body { background: #661A4C; } 
        #main { margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 28px #000; width: 800px; height: 500px; } 
        #caroussel { width: 750px; height: 500px; overflow:hidden; } 
        #caroussel ul { list-style: none; width: 3750px; height: 500px; } 
        #caroussel ul li { float: left; width: 750px; height: 500px; } 
        #caroussel ul img { width: 750px; height: 500px; } 
</style>

<body> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="caroussel"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><img src="http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png" /><li> 
                <li><img src="http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png" /><li> 
                <li><img src="http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png" /><li> 
                <li><img src="http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png" /><li> 
                <li><img src="http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png" /><li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $ul = $('#caroussel  ul');
    setInterval(function() {
      $ul.animate({marginLeft:'-800px'},2000,function(){
        $ul.find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        $ul.css({marginLeft:0});
      });
    },2000);                 

 }); 

</script>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xopuvuqivo/edit?html,output)

Comment: Hmm. There might be a problem with CSS. Can you add the CSS and HTML markup.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: ;
  }
  body {
    background: #661A4C;
  }
  #main {
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 28px #000;
     width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  #caroussel {
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  #caroussel ul {
    list-style: none;
     width: 3750px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  #caroussel ul li {
    float: left;
     width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  #caroussel ul li img {
     width: 7500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  </style>

Comment: <body>
<div id="main">
<div id="caroussel">
  <ul>
  <li><img src="imgs/benbridge.jpg" /><li>
    <li><img src="imgs/gurkhin.jpg" /><li>
    <li><img src="imgs/londoneye.jpg" /><li>
    <li><img src="imgs/shard.jpg" /><li>
    <li><img src="imgs/viewfromgurkhin.jpg" /><li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: Sorry for the code looking so messed up, i could not figure out how to mark it down.

Comment: @ Abhishek, the path to the images are good, the css is inline and the jquery is has not external file either.
Thank you for the mark down tips, i will use that in the future.
Ps: the picture is displayed way way large for some reason.

Comment: No worries. I have fixed it. You can play around with the timer delay (its 2000 now). Replace the images with your own images.

Comment: did you actually put the Jquery code outside the body?

Comment: I can see how it work in the jsbin for you, i still couldnt get it to work in browser...
It looks like not the whole code is listed on the JSbin site.
This is very odd.
Thank you a lot so far btw, much appreciated.